# How to stop an automatic reload of the Grafana Panel

Tags: grafana

When I go into the panel to modify the Grafana Panel or see the settings, all the panels on the Dashboard automatically reload. Is there a way to stop this?

In other words, I would like to stop refreshing as shown in the picture below.
[image]